# Python: pickle creates module import error

Tags: python, pandas, import, pickle

I have a python script which uses pickle that I've been running for weeks.  I recently installed dropbox so that I could run the script on machine A, pickle the data to dropbox, and then load the data from dropbox onto machine B.  So, I used to write to a file in the path of the script, now I write to a separate file synced by dropbox.

When I go to load the data, I get the following error:

```
data = pickle.load(f)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs'
```

However, this prior line works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
```

In fact, if I run the script that's dumping (rather than loading) data, it also runs successfully.

I've also verified the path is correct using sys.path.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It's being called from within pickle.load(f)

Comment: @SamCraig: no, pickle loads objects via a (module, name) reference. You don't store the source of a type, you just store where you can load it from next time.

Comment: @SamCraig: but in this case an object was pickled that states that it lives in the `pd._libs` module. Apparently that module is not available on the other machine.

Comment: Which leads to me believe this is probably a Pandas version issue..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, this is a `pandas` version issue.  Your pickle file was created by pickling objects containing a newer version or `pandas`, and the system unpickling that file contains an older version of `pandas`.

To be more precise, `pandas._libs` first appeared in:

> commit 648ae4f03622d8eafe1ca3b833bd6a99f56bece4
>   Author: Jeff Reback
>    Date:   Tue Mar 7 18:21:18 2017 -0500
>
> BLD: consolidate remaining extensions
>   moves extensions to pandas/_libs, which holds the extension code
>   and also the generated builds (as its importable).

... which first appears in version 0.20.  It stands to reason that your pickle file was created with a version of `pandas` >= 0.20, and the unpickle system has version < 0.20.